# what's the difference between user-level directives and primitive directives in NASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm

In NASM manual, there is only a very simple description:

> NASM's directives come in two types: user-level directives and primitive directives. Typically, each directive has a user-level form and a primitive form. In almost all cases, we recommend that users use the user-level forms of the directives, which are implemented as macros which call the primitive forms.
>
> Primitive directives are enclosed in square brackets; user-level directives are not.

Still I cannot understand the difference, can anybody give an example?

Comment: See [6.3.1 The __SECT__ Macro](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.3) for an example.

Comment: @Jester Thank you, it helps!

Comment: It just mentions "The primitive form, [SECTION xyz], simply switches the current target section to the one given. The user-level form, SECTION xyz, however, first defines the single-line macro __SECT__ to be the primitive [SECTION] directive which it is about to issue, and then issues it. So the user-level directive ". So why would I use one over the other?